# Date Time picker for angular 17.0.8 and node 20.10.0

Tags: node.js, angular17

Needed a date time picker for angular version 17.0.8 and node version 20.10.0.

I installed many packages but none are supported please can you suggest any date time picker for angular version 17.0.8 and node version 20.10.0.

Comment: https://primeng.org/installation

Comment: Angular material does not have date time picker . ngx bootstrap is not working . Primeng  does this have date time picker ? and will it support angular 17?

Comment: https://primeng.org/calendar#time

Comment: Here we can select date only in the present month, but our requirement is user can select date and time of any month or any year . EX: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker

Comment: hmmm what do you mean? You can select any month, any year https://prnt.sc/_I8vBQVN6xzH

Comment: yes , the link you have provided https://prnt.sc/_I8vBQVN6xzH this type itself .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256705/discussion-between-kavya-dengi-and-phoenix404).

Comment: prime ng looks nice but overkill since i only need the time picker.